# Resizable DIV only horizontally

Tags: jquery, resize, drag

I need a plugin to resize a DIV vertically just use jQuery ( not jq UI ). here is a sample of the HTML :

```
<div class="wrapper" style="width:300px; height:300px; padding:50px; border:1px solid black;">

    <div class="resizable" style="height:300px; width:150px; background:green;float:left">

        TEST TEST

    </div>


    <div class="handle" style="width:10px; height:60px; float:left; margin-top:120px; background:red;"> </div>

</div>
```

thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```
jQuery('.resizable').css({
  'height': '150px'
})
```

If you ask nicely, more people would have answered to it by now.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the built-in [height()](http://docs.jquery.com/CSS/height#val) function:

```
$(function ()
{
    $(".resizable").height(300); // .resizable to 300px in height
});
```